# Can two figures (of any kind, bounded by curves or not) have the same area and perimeter, but different shapes?

Tags: general-topology, geometry

> Can two figures (of any kind, bounded by curves or not) have the same area and perimeter, but different shapes?

By "different shape", I mean that you cannot rotate one, take it out of the plane, and/or enlarge/reduce it so that it fits the other.

Answer (score 25):

[image]

(This space intentionally left blank.)

Comment: +1 for this elementary,  instructive and colourful  answer that is only seen once in a Blue moon. (I can guess what answers  users Red or Green would have submitted...)

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: So far as colorful answers go, you might say that this isn't just *elementary*, it's *primary*. :)

Comment: Excellent, dear Blue :-)

Comment: Hmph. https://xkcd.com/608/

Answer (score 8):

These two figures have the same area ancd the same perimeter:

First figure: the right triangle of sides $3,4,5$.

Second figure: the rectangle of sides $3+ \sqrt{3}, 3- \sqrt{3}$.

Comment: Nice, how you arrived at these values? Interested to know.

Comment: @KarriChandrasekhar First, I considered the triangle of sides 3,4,5. It is easy to compute area and perimeter, since it is a right triangle. The area is $6$ and the perimeter is $12$. After that I solved the quadratic equation $$x^2-6x+6=0$$ the two solutions are two numbers $x_1+x_2=6$ and $x_1x_2=6$, hence the rectagle of sides $x_1, x_2$ has area 6 and perimeter 12.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, though the solution is arbitrary.

See the attached image.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Duly acknowledging @Blue 's solution, it seems arbitrarily many such solutions might be possible, one being here, below:

[image]

Can this be extended, perhaps in methodical manner?